# Move game progress to another phone

Tags: backup, games

I want to change my Lumia 820 to 650 and I want to move my games progress. Most games havent sync with fb or other storage. How to move game progress to another phone?

Comment: What OS are you running on your 820 - Windows Phone 8.x or Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: i have seen this possible with farmville2 and asphalt 8 only, remaining were not possible even though some are online games

Answer (score 3):

Starting with WP8.1, some games back up their data (usually including player progress) to Microsoft's servers. However, not even all new games do this, and ones written before WP8.1 (or written to support older OS versions) don't even have the option (short of asking you to enter your OneDrive credentials or something).

There are options, but they're all terribly unofficial and usually somewhat "hacky". Both getting your files off the old phone, and getting them onto the new one, are official not possible. For the old phone, there's actually a lot of options (so long as you're still on WP8.1): use an interop-unlock and capability-unlock hack to browse the file system to the isolated storage folders for apps using an app on the phone, use a "full FS" hack for MTP and do it via USB, use http://www.wpinternals.net/, or put the apps on SD card and use on-phone hacks to get at the app data on the SD card. I can explain these in more detail, but you'd be better off checking sites like http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development for tools and instructions.

Getting the extracted files back onto a 650 is going to be harder. While W10M is actually more permissive than WP8.1 when you're working *without* hacks, it's harder to hack (or at least, we haven't gotten as far yet). SD card hacks may be an option (see [the Lumia 950 forum on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development); most stuff will work on the 650 as well).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a programmer, but such solutions frighten me: P I want to use the phone, do not hack it. People sometimes change phones, restore factory settings, why is problematic adding to transfer game progress?

Comment: @BWA There is nothing problamatic. It's just that the devs have not implemented it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been one of the biggest problems with Windows Phone, clear back to WP7.0. They've improved the migration story a *lot* - SMS now follow you from device to device, for example, and they did finally add the official *ability* for apps to use roaming storage, or to send things through a OneDrive/Dropbox/whatever app without needing to code support for that provider directly - but it's definitely a weak point in the system. As for WHY it's so bad, best guess: if you can backup and restore files, you can edit them; if you can edit game data, you can cheat.