# Is there any way to transfer app data from one phone to another?

Tags: apps, file-transfer, transfer

I have an old phone with a broken power button. I'd like to transfer the app data (emulator save file) onto another windows phone. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your app data to an another phone, but using cloud. Here is how you can do it.

1. Open *Settings->Update & Security-> Backup*.
2. Turn on *Backup content from participating apps*.
3. Click on *Advanced options*.
4. Click *Backup now*.

These backups will be restored while you install apps on the new device. Make sure both are connected to the same Microsoft account.

**Note :** This method does not work for all apps as it is upto the devs to implement it.

---

**For unsupported apps**

There is an unofficial way to restore app data for apps that don't support OneDrive backup. In this way apps are moved to SD card and their app data is edited. I am not familiar with such things. You can refer to [@CBHacking](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/15445/cbhacking)'s answer [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13133/18061) in which he says,

> There are options, but they're all terribly unofficial and usually
>   somewhat "hacky". Both getting your files off the old phone, and
>   getting them onto the new one, are official not possible. For the old
>   phone, there's actually a lot of options (so long as you're still on
>   WP8.1): use an interop-unlock and capability-unlock hack to browse the
>   file system to the isolated storage folders for apps using an app on
>   the phone, use a "full FS" hack for MTP and do it via USB, use
>   http://www.wpinternals.net/, or put the apps on SD card and use
>   on-phone hacks to get at the app data on the SD card. I can explain
>   these in more detail, but you'd be better off checking sites like
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development for tools
>   and instructions. Getting the extracted files back onto a 650 is going
>   to be harder. While W10M is actually more permissive than WP8.1 when
>   you're working without hacks, it's harder to hack (or at least, we
>   haven't gotten as far yet). SD card hacks may be an option (see the
>   Lumia 950 forum on XDA; most stuff will work on the 650 as well).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I can't use the official backup tool since the app isn't supported, so I'll give that WPIntervals thing a try.

Comment: @D.Joe Okay. If you have any doubts regarding that try xda forums or ask the help of CBHacking. The WPInternals was his idea. He could be of more help than I am. Also if it works for you please post it back here with details on what you have tried. It will help others. Thank you in advance.